# Aggregating values in SQL

Tags: sql, function, aggregate, sybase

Im trying to aggregate output values of a customer's bankruptcy in terms of yes (`Y`), no (`N`) or no data (`N/D`) using a window function in a subquery below. For example, if there arise edge cases when in one record the Customer is classified as not bankrupt (`N`) but in another record on the same `CDate` it is also classified as no data (`N/D`), I should get a final aggregated output value as N/D, but it gives me N instead, because of what I've done here by partitioning the customer records over `IsBankrupt` ascending (`asc`). The logic behind it which is supposed to be implemented:

```
Y and Y = Y;
Y and N = Y;
N and N = N;
Y and N/D = Y;
N and N/D = N/D


with sample as (
    select date('2020-12-32') as CDate, 123 as CustomerID, 'N/D' as IsBankrupt
    union all
    select date('2020-12-32') as CDate, 123 as CustomerID, 'N' as IsBankrupt)
select CDate, CustomerID, IsBankrupt, case when CustomerID = 123 then 'N/D' end as ExpectedResult
from
(
    select CDate, CustomerID, IsBankrupt,
        row_number() over (partition by CustomerID, CDate order by IsBankrupt asc) as flag
    from sample
) from subsample
where flag = 1
```

output:

| CDate | CustomerID | IsBankrupt | ExpectedOutput |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-12-31 | 123 | N | N/D |

All the other cases of the previously mentioned logic work. So Question is - how could i update my row_number() over partition by clause so that the logic doesnt break down?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest aggregation:

```
select cdate, customerid,
      (case when sum(case when IsBankrupt = 'Y' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
            then 'Y'
            when sum(case when IsBankrupt = 'N/D' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
            then 'N/D'
            else 'N'
       end) as new_flag
from t
group by cdate, customerid;
```

If you don't like the nested `case` expressions, you can actually do this based on the ordering of the values:

```
select cdate, customerid,
      max(IsBankrupt) as new_flag
from t
group by cdate, customerid;
```

Comment: if the same Customer on the same date has one Y and one N IsBankrupt value, then by your suggested case statement the new_flag shows the same output as IsBankrupt - namely not Y and N = Y, but Y and N = Y and N, so it duplicates the record

Comment: @soundsfierce . . . This returns one row per customer/date combination, which appears to be what your question is asking for.  There is no duplication.  And if any of the values are `'Y'`, it returns `'Y'`, just as your question specifies.